# React Router v6 - How to use @ symbol in route?

Tags: reactjs, react-router, react-router-dom

I'm using react-router-dom to manage my routes:

```
<Routes>
    <Route path="/" element={<MainLayout />}>
        <Route index element={<Home />} />
        <Route path="@:profileId" element={<Profile />} />
    </Route>
<Routes>
```

I want to use @ prefix at profile route but error is `no routes matched location "/@username"`

How to fix it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems there's a [bug](https://github.com/remix-run/react-router/issues/8699) filed for this issue, and 1 or 2 open pull requests in the works. Fortunately (*or unfortunately*) these sorts of paths work fine in non-layout routes.

A workaround until the bug/issue is resolved:

Convert the `MainLayout` into a wrapper component and wrap the routed components individually. Basically consume a `children` prop and render `children` where the `Outlet` component was previously.

Example `MainLayout` layout component:

```
const MainLayout = () => (
  <>
    <h1>MainLayout</h1>
    <Outlet />
  </>
);
```

becomes

```
const MainLayout = ({ children }) => (
  <>
    <h1>MainLayout</h1>
    {children}
  </>
);
```

And the routes from

```
<Routes>
  <Route path="/" element={<MainLayout />}>
    <Route index element={<Home />} />
    <Route path="@:profileId" element={<Profile />} />
  </Route>
</Routes>
```

to

```
<Router>
  <Routes>
    <Route
      path="/"
      element={
        <MainLayout>
          <Home />
        </MainLayout>
      }
    />
    <Route
      path="/@:profileId"
      element={
        <MainLayout>
          <Profile />
        </MainLayout>
      }
    />
  </Routes>
</Router>
```

[image: Edit react-router-v6-how-to-use-symbol-in-route]

It appears this bug has been fixed in [v6.4.3](https://github.com/remix-run/react-router/issues/8699#issuecomment-1291202569). It appears the behavior changed a bit in v6.5 with a caveat when it comes to dynamic route path segments needing to be the full segment, e.g. `"/:profileId"`.

> You can still use special characters, but dynamic parameters
> (`:param`) are required to be full url segments. 6.5.0 included a fix
> to remove inadvertent support for partial params (`/@:param`). There's
> a suggested approach to follow in the release notes if your app was
> relying on this buggy behavior previously.

What this means is that the route path should omit the special characters and apply regex, string manipulation, etc to extract the path token value.

> `path="/:productSlug"`
>
> ```
> function Product() {
>   const { productSlug } = useParams();
>   const [category, product] = productSlug.split("--");
>   // ...
> }
> ```