# How to implement route path with @ symbol

Tags: reactjs, routes, react-router

How to implement route path http://test.com/@alex222 using react-router-dom?

Such route doesn't work:

```
<Route path={'@:userName'} element={<UserPage />} />
```

Everything ok if it hasn't @ symbol.

Comment: Does this help answer your question? https://stackoverflow.com/a/71776570/8690857

Answer (score -1):

It works, but deal was with wrapped Route:

```
 <Routes location={state?.backgroundLocation || location}>
          <Route>
            <Route index element={<MainPage />} />
            <Route path='feed' element={<FeedPage />} />
            <Route
              path='profile'
              element={
                <RequireAuth>
                  <ProfilePage />
                </RequireAuth>
              }
            />
            <Route path={'@:userName'} element={<UserPage />} />
            <Route path='*' element={<NoMatchPage />} />
          </Route>
        </Routes>
```

Thanks, Drew Reese!